# an open ray is a union of closed rays

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X, < )$ is a totally ordered set. Then

$$ (a, \infty) = \bigcup_{x > a} [x, \infty) $$

for any $a \in X$

#### Attempt:

Let $y \in \bigcup_{x > a} [x, \infty) $. So there is some $x > a $ so that $y \geq x $ and so $y > a $. Hence, $x \in (a, \infty) $.

As for the other direction, I am kind of stuck. Would be wise to prove to contrapositive instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful, $x$ is just a dummy variable, you have not shown anything yet.

To show these two sets are equal, you must show $(a,\infty) \subseteq \bigcup_{x > a} [x,\infty)$, and $(a,\infty) \supseteq \bigcup_{x > a} [x,\infty)$.

To show $(a,\infty) \subseteq \bigcup_{x > a} [x,\infty)$, let $r \in (a,\infty)$, you must show $r \in \bigcup_{x>a}[x,\infty)$. We have $r>a$ and $r \in [r,\infty)$, so $r \in \bigcup_{x>a}[x,\infty)$.

To show $(a,\infty) \supseteq \bigcup_{x > a} [x,\infty)$, let $r \in \bigcup_{x > a} [x,\infty)$ be given, and we must show $r \in (a,\infty)$. By definition we may choose an $x>a$ such that $r \in [x,\infty)$. Thus $r\geq x > a$ so $r>a$ and hence $r \in (a,\infty)$.

Thus  $(a,\infty) = \bigcup_{x > a} [x,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! One question, can we write $(2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{Q} $ as a union of closed rays in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Of course, $(2,\infty) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [2+\frac1n,\infty)$, but the statement $(2,\infty)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is of course false. I assume you mean as a union of closed rays with finite left endpoint in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I understand, but it wouldnt work if we replace the rationals with $\mathbb{N}$. correct?

Comment: That's correct, can you show that if $2.5$ is in a set of the form $[a,\infty)$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$, then $2 \in [a,\infty)$?

Comment: I cant prove it. Can you help me solve this? thanks

Comment: If $2.5 \in [a,\infty)$ then $a \leq 2.5$. But $a \in \mathbb{N}$, so $a \leq 2$, and hence $2 \in [a,\infty)$.

Comment: why is the statement $(2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ false ?

Comment: The $\subset$ symbol means "subset", $A \subset B$ means for all $a \in A$, we have $a \in B$. We do not have $(2,\infty) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ because, for instance $\pi \in (2,\infty)$ but $\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I meant $(2, \infty) = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x > 2 \} $

Comment: @WillieRosario, this is also false. Again because $\pi \in (2,\infty)$ but $\pi$ cannot be written as $x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Im confused. $(2, \infty)$ only contain points in $\mathbb{Q}$. and $\pi \notin (2, \infty)$ since $\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: This is not correct. The standard definition of $(a,b)$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}$. You are concerned with $(2,\infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in (a,\infty)$. Then $y>a$ and $y\in [y,\infty)$. Hence $ y\in \cup_{x>a} [x,\infty)$